# Fourier Transform of a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

I have a an image matrix that I converted to grayscale and then pulled one random row from it like so:

```
img = imread('Image.png');
grayImage = rgb2gray(img);
grayImage1 = im2double(grayImage);
vector1 = grayImage1((100),:);
```

I want to do a Fourier Transform of the extracted vector in order to get frequencies correlated to the intensity values of the gray image. I don't really have any knowledge of Fourier transform other than the fact that it converts a signal to a set of frequencies. If I did a sine wave for example, I should see the frequencies and magnitudes of the sine wave and I want to be able to see that with the vector I have. I can try to be more specific if this isn't enough information but any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You quite probably want to perform the cosine discrete transform (CDT) to that image, as it is the "equivalent" in image processing to the fourier transoform for signals. It gives you the fourier transform (without the phase) in 2 dimensions. Read a bit about it in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax named fft.

type

help fft

in your command line